# Issue when creating a deployment slot for Wordpress on App Service

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

When creating a deployment slot and cloning the settings, only some of my files/plugins are being cloned over. The main page shows the theme doesn't exist, the plugins are broken/removed, and when I try to install a plugin with a zip file it says, "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2023/06. Is its parent directory writable by the server?". It also breaks/uninstalls the production deployment slots plugins. (Causes them to deactivate).

I expected the app settings to be cloned over and the deployment slot to load a cloned version of my production slot app, but it breaks the production slot (by deactivating the plugins) and I can not edit any of the plugins in the staging environment. I can edit the content (such as blogs) and change the theme.

Answer (score 0):

My wordpress app deployed in Azure app service:-

[image]

While cloning settings in Azure Web App deployment slot, Make sure you validate the settings from Production slot and after validation is completed apply settings like below:-

[image]

***When I switched the Slots, The Wordpress app ran successfully in another slot, Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2023/06. Is its parent directory writable by the server?". It also breaks/uninstalls the production deployment slots plugins. (Causes them to deactivate).

This error is specific to Wordpress file in order to resolve this error refer the steps below:-

This error occurs if Wordpress is not able to load the location of uploads folder. This occurs also if Deployment slot has not validated complete files and plugins to another slot. To fix this,  Refer the solutions from this [**blog**](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/fix-the-is-its-parent-directory-writable-by-the-server-wordpress-error) by Hostinger.

According to the blog above:-

1. Try to get the Wordpress config file. You can find that file in Azure Web app by visiting:-
   ***Web app > Advanced Tools > Kudu > site/wwwroot > And find **wp-config.php***** and add this line of code below:-

[image]

[image]

> ```
> define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
> ```
>
> before this line:-
>
> ```
> require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
> ```

2. Change the Folder permission:-

Select **wp-content folder** and check if you have appropriate permissions and you can access it via Kudu tool like below:-

Also, Click on Bash at the top of the tool and cd into wp-content > and add the chown permissions on the File like below:-

```bash
ls
cd site 
cd wwwroot
cd wp-content
```

> ```bash
> chown -R www-data:www-data uploads
> chmod 755 -R uploads
> ```

[image]

Also, Make validate if all the files are added in your Production slot is same as your test slot like below:-

**Test Slot:-**

[image]

**Production Slot:-**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the in-depth response! I am trying to go through the process you described, but you mentioned adding a line of code inside the wp-config file inside of the /wwwroot/ pathway. How do you go about doing that? Most resources I am coming across about using Kudu to edit files, brings up a window that shows the files and an edit button. I'm not sure how to get there since they click a button in the header that I do not have. Thank you again for helping answer this!

Comment: Oh, I also attempted the second method according to the article (and your answer), and I found out that the uploads folder inside of WP-content does not exist at all in the deployment slot files. Why do you think that happened and how would you attempt to fix it?