# Production/Staging for WordPress on Azure App Service

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I setup production/staging slots for Wordpress for Azure App Service?  I am completely at sea.

I have my WordPress site running in the production slot.  Everything is working fine.  Now I want to setup a staging slot so that I can experiment with various changes.

I clone the production slot and I discover that the cloned staging slot is simply an empty WordPress installation.  None of my plugins or themes are installed.  What is going on?  How can this possibly work?

I am used to Pressidium which has production and staging environments for WordPress.  You copy production to staging.  Modify staging and then copy staging to production.  Works great!

I am also used to production and staging slots in Azure.  You deploy code via GitHub actions or similar to the staging slot.  When you are ready you swap the production and staging slots.  Works great!

How do you do this for WordPress on Azure App Service?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Azure Wordpress app to get deployed in the deployment slot properly, Refer my SO answer here.

***Step 1:-***

While creating the slot make sure you **`clone the settings`** of you Production App for your staging app to load properly by selecting the Production app like below:-

Created ***Staging slot*** and **cloned the settings of the app running in the Production slot:-**

[image]

This will make sure the ***Database and other settings from Production Slot is added to the Staging slot correctly***:-

As you are using Github Actions, You can also refer the Steps outlined in this Document- [wordpress-linux-appservice/WordPress/wordpress_azure_StageDeployments.md at main · Azure/wordpress-linux-appservice (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/wordpress-linux-appservice/blob/main/WordPress/wordpress_azure_StageDeployments.md) > ***`To Configure Deployment Slots in Wordpress deployment to App Service correctly.`***

Also, After you create a Staging Slot by cloning the settings from Production Slot, You can visit the Staging Slot and configure Github Action workflow via Deployment Center separately for Staging slot and separately for Production Slot.

[image]

**My output:-**

*Production Slot:-*

[image]

*Staging Slot:-*

[image]

Also Refer my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483775/issue-when-creating-a-deployment-slot-for-wordpress-on-app-service/76488050#) to resolve the deployment slot issues for the Wordpress App. and 1) Edit your *****wp-config.php***** according to my answer. 2) Change your **wp-content** folder permissions accoridng to my answer

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I've studied your answer and the referenced posts carefully.  I'm still lost.  It seems that to copy the plug-ins and themes from the production to the staging slot you need to copy Azure blob.  (1) My production slot has no mounted filesystems.  So I can't figure out how to fix this or whether I am simply looking in the wrong place for the blob. (2) The wp_options record in the WP database has entries for site URL and home.  These fields have to be different between production and staging.  Don't see where this is done in your approach.

Comment: The wp_options record in the WP database has entries for site URL and home. These fields have to be different between production and staging. Don't see where this is done in your approach. >> If the fields for WP database is different for staging, you will have to add the setting manually for each App. As these two apps in the slots act differently